# Tokio channel rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I am trying to implement a Promise system with Tokio, I simulate the callback and the resolve, this is the code:

```
use std::time::Duration;

use tokio::sync::oneshot::{channel};
use tokio::time::sleep;

async fn task_prom(callback: impl Fn(i32)) {
    for x in 1..=10 {
        if x == 10 {
            callback(x);
        }
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }
}

async fn handler() -> i32 {
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<i32>();
    task_prom(move |x| tx.send(x).unwrap()).await;
    rx.await.unwrap()
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let res = handler().await;
    println!("{}", res);
}
```

When I try to run, I get this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `tx`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure


--> src\main.rs:17:24
    |
16  |     let (tx, rx) = channel::<i32>();
    |          -- captured outer variable
17  |     task_prom(move |x| tx.send(x).unwrap()).await;
    |               -------- ^^ ------- `tx` moved due to this method call
    |               |        |
    |               |        move occurs because `tx` has type `tokio::sync::oneshot::Sender<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |               captured by this `Fn` closure
    |
note: `tokio::sync::oneshot::Sender::<T>::send` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `tx`
   --> C:\Users\titof\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.28.1\src\sync\oneshot.rs:594:21
    |
594 |     pub fn send(mut self, t: T) -> Result<(), T> {
    |

                 ^^^^
```

I see the Tokio's documentation, but I don't know why I have this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a oneshot channel can only be used once, you can't capture and then use it in a [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) or [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) closure. The closure must consume it, so it needs to be a [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) closure.

```rs
async fn task_prom(callback: impl FnOnce(i32))
```

Unfortunately, this still doesn't compile.

```rs
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `callback`
 --> src/main.rs:9:13
  |
6 | async fn task_prom(callback: impl FnOnce(i32)) {
  |                    -------- move occurs because `callback` has type `impl FnOnce(i32)`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
9 |             callback(x);
  |             ^^^^^^^^---
  |             |
  |             `callback` moved due to this call, in previous iteration of loop
  |
note: this value implements `FnOnce`, which causes it to be moved when called
 --> src/main.rs:9:13
  |
9 |             callback(x);
  |             ^^^^^^^^
help: consider further restricting this bound
  |
6 | async fn task_prom(callback: impl FnOnce(i32) + Copy) {
  |                                               ++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

Rust does not statically know how many times a for loop is run. It also doesn't statically know which branch in an if expression will run. So you need to restructure your code to ensure `callback` is only run once. How you do this will depend on the function, but in this case you can just move it outside the loop.

```rs
async fn task_prom(callback: impl FnOnce(i32)) {
    for x in 1..10 {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }
    callback(10);
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
}
```

You could also insert a `return` in the same path as the `callback` call.

```rs
async fn task_prom(callback: impl FnOnce(i32)) {
    for x in 1..=10 {
        if x == 10 {
            callback(x);
            sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            return;
        }
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }
}
```

Aside from the iterator in for loops and the condition in if, match, and while, rust is pretty smart about when branches can be taken.

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand what you are trying to do here, but your code can be made to compile by changing `impl Fn(i32)` to `impl FnOnce(i32)`, and then calling `callback` once after the `for` loop instead of within the loop:

```rust
async fn task_prom(callback: impl FnOnce(i32)) {
    for _ in 1..10 {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }
    callback(10);
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
}
```

As the error message mentions, `send` moves out of `tx`, so the closure can only be executed once, so you need to use `FnOnce`, the trait that indicates a function can only be called once. Then you need to move `callback` out of the loop body so that Rust knows that it will only be called once.

All of this is because you are using a oneshot channel that can only be sent on once; this is fine so long as you only need to execute the callback once. Other channels would allow you to call `send` more than once, if that's what you want.

Edit: fixed code to match @drewtato's more detailed answer since that is more correct (there should be a final sleep after the callback is executed, which I had missed at first).